# How can Apple Script open a shell script with options in a Terminal window?

Tags: applescript, script, command-line

I’m trying to use Apple Script to execute a shell script file in a new Terminal window, while sending it options. How do I do that?

It seems as if Terminal only interprets the path to the script, and ignores what comes next.

I'd like to use something like that:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal " & pathToScript & " -option"
```

The script runs but it doesn't get `-option`.

Note: I need a Terminal window for user interaction. Running the script directly executes it in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following AppleScript works for me:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "~/testscript" & " -arg1" & " -arg2"
end tell
```